# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (NullreferenceException was unhandled by user code)

Tags: asp.net, syntax, nullreferenceexception, literals

How can I get around this exception?

```
Dim imagepathlit As Literal = DownloadsRepeater.FindControl("imagepathlit")
        imagepathlit.Text = imagepath
```

Here is the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="DownloadsRepeater" runat="server">

<HeaderTemplate>
<table width="70%">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><h2>Files you can download</h2></td>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<tr>
<td width="5%">
<asp:Literal ID="imagepathlit" runat="server"></asp:Literal></td>
<td width="5%"></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the code that gets the data for the repeater:

```
c.Open()
        r = x.ExecuteReader
        While r.Read()
            If r("filename") Is DBNull.Value Then
                imagepath = String.Empty
            Else
                imagepath = "<img src=images/" & getimage(r("filename")) & " border=0 align=absmiddle>"
            End If

        End While
        c.Close()
        r.Close()
```

Comment: More explanation is required and add related code

Comment: could you paste the repeater aspx part? For sure imagepathlit doesn't exist where you're looking for it. If you paste the aspx we could answer with the appropriate way of doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that there is no control found in the `DownloadsRepeater` control called `imagepathlit`, therefore the `imagepathlit` control is null after the call.

Remember that `Control.FindControl()` looks up the control based on `ID`, not the name of the control. Therefore, to find the control in the collection...you would have to had something like this earlier in the application:

```
Dim imagepathlit As Literal = new Literal()
imagepathlit.ID = "imagepathlit"
```

**UPDATE**

Since you're using a repeater, the child controls get layed out a bit differently. You're going to have an instance of the `Literal` for each `Item` in the `Repeater`. Therefore, to get each instance of the control, you have to loop through the `Items` in the `Repeater` and call `FindControl()` on each `Item`:

```
For Each item As Item In DownloadsRepeater.Items
    Dim imagepathlit As Literal = item.FindControl("imagepathlit")
Next
```

Comment: The literal is in the .aspx like this;   <asp:Literal ID="imagepathlit" runat="server"></asp:Literal>

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the code you posted is where the exception is indeed thrown, I would say that the `DownloadRepeater` does not have a control in it that has an ID of `imagepathlit`.

Check your `aspx`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the control is within the ItemTemplate, you cannot use repeater.findcontrol; you have to loop through the items of the repeater to look for the control, as the itemtemplate is repeatable.  So you have to loop through each one to look for the control as in:

```
foreach (var item in repeater.Items)
{
   var control = item.FindControl("ID") as Type;
}
```

Use that syntax.